# How can I package a module with a jquery-plugin in a sober way?

Tags: 7

I'm almost getting crazy with this...

My Problem: I have a module with its own css and jquery-plugin. When i add it directly to the theme.info via scripts[] everything is fine. But when i try to integrate it with  drupal_add_js() from out of the mymodule.module I get a Reference Error

> jQuery.noConflict();

how do i load the jquery plugin from my module in my relative path mymodule/js/javascript.js?

I already checked out what others wrote. The plugin starts with 
(function($).. and ends with })(jQuery)

What else can I do?

Comment: after using `drupal_add_js` have you checked the "page source"? is the js file loaded properly?

Comment: @vimalnath thanks for asking... The source is loaded...as far as chrome tells me...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061397/jquery-noconflict-issue this might help you 

Actually this issue happens when there is a conflict in the DOM objects.`http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/`

Comment: @vimalnath thank you for the link...what i don't understand is: why drupal has no problems, when i add it to the template info file...

Comment: By default, drupal includes a `jquery.js`, check if you are over-writing it.Also check if your jquery plugin is compatible with drupal's jquery version